# A simple php script does not return same size answer all the time

Tags: php

I have a simple "what's my ip" running. It gets called by ajax every 5 seconds.

The php is simply `<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>`

But, looking in the `apache` server log at requests from the *same client, same browser*, a table of the size of the frequencies vs the size of requests, shows the output size is not consistent.

I do not use cookies on that site.

```
467 417
164 570
140 385
 40 538
 15 4205
  4 4173
  1 600
  1 5834
  1 559
  1 530
  1 2002
```

How can the size vary? Same question, same answer, I would assume.

...
**Edit:**

When I do curl -i, I get this; size 330. But the size transferred as shown in log is consistently 3956 bytes?!?

The server is on https; so some certificate exchange is being done, still it should be the same?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 06 Dec 2018 08:46:21 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) SVN/1.9.5 PHP/5.6.30-0+deb8u1 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.13 OpenSSL/1.0.2l mod_perl/2.0.10 Perl/v5.24.1
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30-0+deb8u1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 10
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: What exactly are we looking at here? Frequency on the left, size in bytes on the right?

Comment: Even the smallest 385 bytes would be *waaaay* too large a response value for a simple IP. Does that include headers or just the body?

Comment: Can you provide a sample response your server would give?

Comment: A sample response: "192.168.1.112"

Comment: Can you include the response headers too? Can you *measure* the size? On a *NIX command line: `$ curl -i localhost...` and `$ curl -i localhost... | wc`.